# Mostrar todos los datos en una tabla PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, html5, tablas

Lo que quiero es mostrar todos los registros de una tabla `(SQL)` en `PHP` por medio de una tabla.

Esta es la tabla:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="table-success table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
                <th>Fecha de nacimiento</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo $row['id'] ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $row['nombre'] ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $row['apellido'] ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $row['edad'] ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $row['fecha_de_nacimiento'] ?></th>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

este es el codigo `PHP` con el que llamo a los registros

```
<?php 
include("funcionalidad/conexion.php");
$conn = conectar();

$sql = "SELECT *  FROM usuario";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
?>
```

lo raro es que si funciona, pero no como me lo esperaba ya que tengo 2 registros en la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero solo me muestra uno en el `PHP`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haz hecho un while... y mandas solo UN código html. Lo que debes hacer es cambiar eso para que se genere dinámicamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomendaría hacerlo con foreach amigo, con while solo envías un dato.

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($query as $row) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $row['id'] ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $row['nombre'] ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $row['apellido'] ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $row['edad'] ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $row['fecha_de_nacimiento'] ?></th>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 3):

La manera correcta y moderna seria la siguiente almacenar primero todo y luego expones el html.

Separa lo mas que puedas el html de la logica en php ayuda a poder darle un mejor mantenimiento y si tu logica falla se rompera tu codigo php y no tu html, cuando llegues a usar plantillas lo agradeceras.

```
<?php
//esto normalmente esta en una clase que maneja consultas Genericas a la base de datos:
function getTable($tabla){
    include("funcionalidad/conexion.php");
    $conn = conectar();
    $sql = "SELECT *  FROM $tabla";
    return mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}

//esto esta en una capa/clase que se encarga de tomar datos y acomodarlos
function iterateDataToTable($data){
    $lines='';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        $lines.='<tr>
                <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['nombre'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['apellido'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['edad'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['fecha_de_nacimiento'].'</td>
            </tr>'; 
    }
    return $lines;
}

$data=getTable('usuario');
$lines=iterateDataToTable($data);

?>


<div class="col-md-8">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="table-success table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
                <th>Fecha de nacimiento</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                echo $lines;
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como menciono, no estás generando el html dinamico.
Estás siempre mandando el último registro, por lo que no se insertan nuevos datos.

Lo que debes cambiar, es esta parte del `tbody`, a lo sgte:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    foreach($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>" . $row['id'] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row['nombre'] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row['apellido'] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row['edad'] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row['fecha_de_nacimiento'] . "</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```